# MySQL Handling of Ã i utf8 group by primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a utf8 table in mysql 5.5.19.

When I select data from it, I get data such as RoÃdorf and Rosdorf on different rows.

When I group by on the data however, or select distinct, I get only RoÃdorf.

My basic problem is that the data is exported to hive (which gets the correct group by with both different alternatives) and then imports this to mysql again. The import will then fail because mysql will treat RoÃdorf and Rosdorf as the same key (and PK constraint will brake). I guess this is for the same reason as the above distinction, so an answer to that is very helpful.

Comment: This sounds like broken data entered your DB at some point (but not for all rows)

Answer (score 0):

Use `utf8_bin` as collation, it will differentiate accented and non-accented characters

See [MySQL collation charts](http://collation-charts.org/)